# Can OSGi fragments have other fragments as hosts?

Tags: osgi, osgi-fragment

Is this legal?

MANIFEST.MF for `org.fragment1` (`org.host` is a normal bundle, not a fragment):

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.fragment1
Fragment-Host: org.host
```

MANIFEST.MF for `org.fragment2`:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.fragment2
Fragment-Host: org.fragment1
```

Or should `org.fragment2` instead have

```
Fragment-Host: org.host
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fragment bundles can't have a other fragment bundles as host. Only normal bundles can act as an fragment-host.
So your third example is correct:

> Or should `org.fragment2` instead have
>
> `Fragment-Host: org.host`

You find this restriction in the [OSGi Service Platform Release 4 Version 4.3 Core Specification](http://www.osgi.org/download/r4v43/r4.core.pdf) on page 70. It says:

> A Fragment bundle can not be required by another bundle with the Require-Bundle header.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a cite confirming this? I've run into the first example in a project and want to report this as a bug. OSGi specification paragraph 3.14 doesn't seem to say anything about it...

Comment: But there is no `Require-Bundle` header here, only `Fragment-Host`.

Comment: I think we _can_ say "All classes and resources within the fragment bundle must be loaded using the class loader of the host bundle" and "Fragments ... must not have their own class loader" together imply fragments can't be hosts, but it seems a slight stretch.

Answer (score 3):

Fragments attach to hosts. They cannot attach to other fragments. You can construct capabilities and requirements (new in Core 4.3) to prevent a fragment from attaching to a host unless another fragment is also attached. For example, fragment 1 could provide a capability which fragment 2 requires. This may provide the level of control you seek.